# %20 at the end of query string

Tags: asp.net

I'd like to ask, is it possible in asp.net to still read a URI as valid given that it has %20 at the end of it? for example:

```
localhost/mysite/1234%20
```

I need to get the Id 1234 but asp.net is giving me a response code of 404. But if I tried the same URI except that I replaced %20 with a white space, page load is successful

I'm asking this cause if I wasn't mistaken %20 is the same as a white space so I'm trying to make them behave in the same manner

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have a space appended at the end of the URL Parameter.. Use `.trim()` before appending it to the route parameters.